# Transactions that have outputs value more then inputs value possible?

Tags: transactions

Transactions have 2 ways to get into blockchain in bitcoind:

- mempool -> newblock
- newblock no in mempool

lets check **AcceptToMemoryPool** function

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/c719cefc417cc578f48b33069b764339a61054ce/src/main.cpp#L876

```
CAmount nFees = nValueIn-nValueOut;
```

in case outs > ins

nFees<0

```
if (mempoolRejectFee > 0 && nFees < mempoolRejectFee) {
        return state.DoS(0, false, REJECT_INSUFFICIENTFEE, "mempool min fee not met", false, strprintf("%d < %d", nFees, mempoolRejectFee));
```

negative nFees will be rejected all is good in this point

ok
lets check **Connectblock**  function

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/c719cefc417cc578f48b33069b764339a61054ce/src/main.cpp#L1805

for each tx in block we do:

```
nFees += view.GetValueIn(tx)-tx.GetValueOut();
```

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/c719cefc417cc578f48b33069b764339a61054ce/src/main.cpp#L1826

```
 CAmount blockReward = nFees + GetBlockSubsidy(pindex->nHeight, chainparams.GetConsensus());
if (block.vtx[0].GetValueOut() > blockReward)
    return state.DoS(100,
                     error("ConnectBlock(): coinbase pays too much (actual=%d vs limit=%d)",
                           block.vtx[0].GetValueOut(), blockReward),
                           REJECT_INVALID, "bad-cb-amount");
```

At this point we calculate max possible reward for this block: all tx fees + mining reward

then we check that coinbase reward not more then this value

what if same miner create and include transaction that have inputs for 1 btc and have outputs for 2 btc, so fee for this tx will be -1 btc

then miner can set reward for coinbase transaction to  25 btc  + all fees - 1 btc.

so this (block.vtx[0].GetValueOut() > blockReward)  return True

as result we have Transaction, that  create more coins then received, inside blockchain

Where is my error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That isn't allowed, even within a block. Here is the code that checks for that:

main.cpp: [ConnectBlock](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/c719cefc417cc578f48b33069b764339a61054ce/src/main.cpp#L1695)

```
    if (!CheckInputs(tx, state, view, fScriptChecks, flags, false, nScriptCheckThreads ? &vChecks : NULL))
        return error("ConnectBlock(): CheckInputs on %s failed with %s",
            tx.GetHash().ToString(), FormatStateMessage(state));
```

main.cpp: [CheckInputs](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/c719cefc417cc578f48b33069b764339a61054ce/src/main.cpp#L1361)

```
if (!Consensus::CheckTxInputs(tx, state, inputs, GetSpendHeight(inputs)))
    return false;
```

main.cpp: [CheckTxInputs](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/c719cefc417cc578f48b33069b764339a61054ce/src/main.cpp#L1316)

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < tx.vin.size(); i++)
{
    const COutPoint &prevout = tx.vin[i].prevout;
    const CCoins *coins = inputs.AccessCoins(prevout.hash);
    // [11 lines snipped]
    nValueIn += coins->vout[prevout.n].nValue;
    // [3 lines snipped]
}

if (nValueIn < tx.GetValueOut())
    return state.DoS(100, false, REJECT_INVALID, "bad-txns-in-belowout", false,
        strprintf("value in (%s) < value out (%s)", FormatMoney(nValueIn), FormatMoney(tx.GetValueOut())));
```

Comment: main.cpp : line 1346  and line 1352   why checking 2 times?

Comment: @bitaps Dunno. Why not, though?